# Proof or counterexample : Supremum and infimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, supremum-and-infimum

If $($An$)_{n \in N}$ are sets such that each $A_n$ has a supremum and $∩_{n \in N}$$A_n$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$ , then $∩_{n \in N}$$A_n$ has a supremum.

How to Prove This.

Comment: Hint: Let $ \emptyset \neq A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb R,$ and $B$ is bounded above. Then $A$ is also bounded above.

Comment: This statement is True, right ?

Comment: Yes! The statement is true.

Comment: I am still having doubt on how to proceed for this question. PLease Help show if you can.

Comment: Please check the below answer, We have a counterexample as well for the statement, hence I think it must be False statement

Comment: You need to mention what is your definition of supremum and also what is the base space. Both the answers below are right, but in different context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.

I bring you a counter example.

consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as the universal set with the following set definitions:

$$A_1=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}\cup{\{5\}}$$

$$A_2=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}\cup{\{6\}}$$

$$A_n=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}\cup{\{4+n\}}$$

In this example, sumpermum of $A_1$ is 5 and for $A_2$ is 6.

However, $A_1 \cap A_2$ has no supremum:

$$A_1 \cap A_2=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}$$

And so on:

$$A_1 \cap A_2 \cap ... =\{x\in \mathbb{Q}|x^2<2\}$$

However, in $\mathbb{R}$ as a universal set, any bounded non-empty set has a supremum.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\emptyset \neq A \subseteq B \subseteq \mathbb R,$ and $B$ is bounded above. Then there is a real number $u$ such that $b \leq u, \forall b \in B.$ In particular, $a \leq u, \forall a \in A.$ This shows that $A$ is bounded above.

In this particular case, $\cap A_n \subseteq A_n$ and each $A_n$ is bounded above (since they  have supremum). So $\cap A_n$ is bounded above. Now the completeness property of real numbers says that every non-empty subset of $\mathbb R,$ which is bounded above has a supremum.

***Note:*** Since OP didn't mentioned anything about $A_n,$ I assume that the base space is $\mathbb R.$ If it's not $\mathbb R,$ then the statement is no longer true (see other answer for an counter example).

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$. Since $x$ belongs to each $A_n$, $x \le sup\ A_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$. Then we see that $\{x : x \in \cap_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n\}$ is bounded above (by $sup\ A_1$ for example) and so by the Completeness Property of $\mathbb R$, $\cap_{n \in \mathbb N} A_n$ has a supremum.